# phpMyAdmin, Multiple Servers one Page

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, localhost

I'm running phpMyAdmin from a game node that runs WISP game panel. I have everything setup properly to their guide,

Creating a server in /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

`$i++;`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Database Server Name 2';`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.1.102';`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';`
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;`

Which works flawlessly. There is nothing wrong with the code I put in above. My only problem is the node that is running the phpMyAdmin comes up on the option list as localhost:3306, is there a way I can change that verbose / name?

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3Exx.png)

I've tried to create a new server

`$i++;`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'New Name';`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'local host';`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;`

while making the host - localhost hoping it would override the current setup.

Thanks!